# How can I use my Firefox cookies with Selenium?

Tags: selenium, python-3.x

I'm currently setting up a Python script to sign up on a website for me, but every time I start it I have to sign in by myself, and the username/password is not saved.

Question: is it possible to use the cookies from my Firefox profile in the script? Can this be done on Chrome?

Comment: There's an `add_cookie` method you can use on a `WebDriver` instance, which I've used successfully. However, I've never tried extracting cookies from a Firefox profile so I don't know how you'd do this bit.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try the following:

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("general.useragent.override", "some UA string")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
```

Visit "Cookies" for more details and examples!

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Changing the User Agent does nothing, nothing **at all** about the cookies that the browser started by Selenium has.